# sheetJS: How should the cell object look when you want to transform milliseconds to h:mm?

Tags: javascript, format, js-xlsx

Does someone have an idea how the cell object should look like when you want to transform a value in milliseconds to a duration format of h:mm?

At the moment I have a cell object which looks like
`{ t: 'n', v: value, z: 'h:mm' }`
but it doesn't display the correct hour and minutes.

Answer (score 0):

The `z` attribute is deprecated. Try this: `{ t: 'n', v: value, s: { numFmt: 'h:mm' } }`

Comment: Where did you see that `z` attribute is deprecated? I am not able to find it in the [changelog](https://github.com/SheetJS/sheetjs/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md). It even seems that `s` is a pro feature.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const unixEpochMilliseconds = moment().valueOf();

const ws = XLSX.utils.aoa_to_sheet([
  ["a", "string"],
  [1, "number"],
  [{
    t: "d",
    v: moment(unixEpochMilliseconds).toDate(),
    z: "h:mm"
  }, "time"]
]);

const table = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_html(ws);
document.body.innerHTML = table;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.26.0/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/xlsx/0.16.2/xlsx.js"></script>
```